# Any <script> tag in my blade file cause a [Vue warn]: Error compiling template, error -- How do I resolve this?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Laravel Spark 6.0.

Every page (blade) I create that has any script tag in it cause a[Vue warn]: Error compiling template message in the inspector.

It's not obvious that anything is breaking, but it worries me seeing giant error messages in the inspector console.

This is all that is required to causes the error

I assume that I need to put my scripts elsewhere. Or, are script tags incompatible with vue js.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that adding 'scripts' inside the @section('content') creates loads of errors in the inspector console. (Though things seem to work)

If you put your scripts after the @section('content'), they work and your console will be clean. If you care about such things... and I do.